# Beautifulsoup finding a specific value in meta tags

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find all the meta tags that have author in it. It works if I have a specific key and Regex value. It doesn't work when both are Regex. Is it possible to extract all the meta tags on the page containing "author" keyword in it?
This is the code I wrote.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get(url)
contents = page.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')
preys = soup.find_all("meta", attrs={re.compile('.*'): re.compile('author')})
```

Edit:
For clarification, the problem I am trying to solve specifically is if the value "author" is mapped to any key. That key could be "itemprop", "name" or even "property" as I have seen in various examples. Basically, my problem is pulling all the meta tags that has author as a value in it regardless what key that value has.
A couple examples that are the case:

```
<meta content="Jami Miscik" name="citation_author"/>
<meta content="Will Ripley, Joshua Berlinger and Allison Brennan, CNN" itemprop="author"/>
<meta content="Alison Griswold" property="author"/>
```

Comment: Does the documentation suggest somewhere that the attribute name can be a regex? I can't find any hint of that under https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attrs

Comment: That might be the case. If so, I will have to gather all the potential keys and check their values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for `citation_author` or `author`, you might get along with a combination of `soup.select()` and a regular expression:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

# some test string
html = '''
<meta name="author" content="Anna Lyse">
<meta name="date" content="2010-05-15T08:49:37+02:00">
<meta itemprop="author" content="2010-05-15T08:49:37+02:00">
<meta rel="author" content="2010-05-15T08:49:37+02:00">
<meta content="Jami Miscik" name="citation_author"/>
<meta content="Will Ripley, Joshua Berlinger and Allison Brennan, CNN" itemprop="author"/>
<meta content="Alison Griswold" property="author"/>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')

rx = re.compile(r'(?<=)"(?:citation_)?author"')

authors = [author 
            for author in soup.select("meta")
            if rx.search(str(author))]

print(authors)
```

Comment: The syntax I was trying to remember — and couldn't find in the doc.

Comment: @BillBell: It's somewhat hidden and can be found under https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors - *Test for the existence of an attribute:*

Comment: Thank you. I keep saying I'm going to try to write the BS doc in some different form — for people like me.

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem I am trying to solve specifically is if the value "author" is mapped to any key. That key could be itemprop, name or even property as I have seen in various examples. This solution assumes the key will be "name" which might not be the case.

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it. I regret I couldn't find a page quickly that has an `author` `meta` in it that would demonstrate the validity of this code. If you find something wrong please let me know.

```
>>> import requests
>>> import bs4
>>> page = requests.get('http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/meta').text
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> [item.attrs['name'] for item in soup('meta') if item.has_attr('name')]
['robots', 'description']
>>> [item.attrs['name'] for item in soup('meta') if item.has_attr('name') and item.attrs['name'].lower()=='author']
[]
```

Edit: Works with Jan's chunk of html too. His syntax is nicer; use that.

```
>>> html = '<meta name="author" content="Anna Lyse"> <meta name="date" content="2010-05-15T08:49:37+02:00">'
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
>>> [item.attrs['name'] for item in soup('meta') if item.has_attr('name') and item.attrs['name'].lower()=='author']
['author']
```

Comment: Just construct a sample string :)

Comment: ... and why didn't I think of that?

Comment: You're the psychiatrist.

Comment: :) I guess forgetting some of the syntax of `BeautifulSoup` isn't a criterion for a mental disorder - at least none that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Jan: I've used your HTML in an edit to my answer. Thanks for that too.